# Function not defined at one point and discontinuity

Tags: real-analysis

If $f(x)$ $=0$, for all $x$ in $[-1,1]$, but not defined on $0$ then do we say that $f$ is discontinuous at $0$ or do we rather say $f$ is continuous at $0$ since $0$ is not a limit point and then by definition it is continuous?

If $f(x)$ $=0$, for all $x$ in $[-1,1]$ but $f(x)=1$ if $x=0$ then I am guessing in this way $f$ is discontinuous on $0$?

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia as an article about the [classification of discontinuities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_discontinuities). Your first function has a removable discontinuity. Your second one a jump discontinuity.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of continuity at $a$ invoves the limit at $a$ and the value at $a$: the two must (exist and) be equal.

Since in your first question you specify that $0$ is not in the domain of $f$ that function is neither continuous nor discontinuous there - you can't even ask the question.

Your guess is right for the second question.